# Why are there white circles after removing animations?

Tags: object-mode

Recently, I was trying to animate some of my objects. After removing the animations, white circles appeared close to the previously animated objects. What are they and how do I remove them?

[image]
[image]

Comment: I don't know, maybe they are particles?

Comment: They looks like object origins ... Can you select the point?

Comment: I can select them

Comment: Sorry for delay I didn't get notification ... Please share your file delete all just keep few dots so we can expect the issue. ... Sure in case you are looking for an answer ... https://blend-exchange.com